# Understand the code of Split file to fasta

Tags: awk

I understand the matching pattern but how the sequence is read from the matching pattern as the code is matching only pattern ">chr" then how sequence goes to the output file?

```
awk '/^>chr/ {OUT=substr($0,2) ".fa"}; {print >> OUT; close(OUT)}' Input_File
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please always do wrap your samples, efforts in CODE TAGS in your posts by using `{}` button. Also try to use search functionality  before your posting your question, it will help you too, cheers and happy learning on this great site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please go through following explanation once.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program here.
/^>chr/{                         ##Checking condition if any line starts from string chr then do following.
  OUT=substr($0,2) ".fa"         ##Creating variable OUT whose value is substring of first 2 letters and concatenating .fa string to it.
}                                ##Closing block for condition ^>chr here.
{
  print >> OUT                   ##Printing current line to variable OUT value which is formed above and is writing output into out file.
  close(OUT)                     ##If we keep writing lot of files we will get "Too  many files opened error(s)" so closing these files in backend to avoid that error.
}
' Input_File                     ##Mentioning Input_file here which we are processing through awk.
```